# JMS Connection resets in Spring JMS for long running requests

Tags: java, jms, tibco, spring-jms

I am facing a problem while using the DefaultMessageListenerContainer in Spring JMS with TIBCO queues. When I put a relatively small message on a queue, the listener on the queue takes a few seconds to read the message and complete the procesing and everthing works smoothly. On the other hand, when I put a request on the queue that may take longer to be processed by the business layer, I get the following exception a few minutes after the processing begins.

```
04:38:14.392 [TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-34171)] WARN  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
        at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:509) ~[tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._invokeOnExceptionCallback(TibjmsConnection.java:2025) [tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._onDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:2394) [tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection$ServerLinkEventHandler.onEventDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:349) [tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.work(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:330) [tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:259) [tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
```

The processing continues on the listener side and I get the following exception once the listener has finished processing the message :

```
07:28:04.281 [jmsContainer-1] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.getTransacted(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:4837) ~[tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:344) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at $Proxy20.getTransacted(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:572) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:481) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) [org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) [org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1059) [org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1051) [org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:948) [org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_03]
07:28:04.281 [jmsContainer-1] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Queue[cmb.cmbtech.na.bead_153036.rwacalrequest1]' - trying to recover. Cause: Session is closed
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.getTransacted(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:4837) ~[tibjms.jar:6.3.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:344) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at $Proxy20.getTransacted(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:572) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:481) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1059) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1051) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:948) ~[org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_03]
```

And finally, a few seconds after the above exception, I get the following info in the logs

```
07:28:04.418 [jmsContainer-1] INFO  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

I am not really sure what is causing the probelm but it seems that the jms connection is getting reset whenever the listener takes more than a few minutes to process the message. The side effect of all this is that the listener fails to publish the processing output to another queue for an external application to consume. Do I need to set a transaction manager for my listener or set some kind of property that will not reset the connection for a given duration?

Comment: What code would you like to see? As far as my understanding goes, I am facing this issue for messages that require a considerable amount of time to be processed. Please note that when I say a messge takes considerable amount of time to process, it doesn't mean that message is large. It only means that the message goes through some complex business logic that can take a few minutes to complete! That being said, I don't think the business logic should really impact the JMS layer.

Comment: Have you tried manual message ack?

Comment: I suspect Tibco thinks the client has hung - explore the broker settings - look for a timeout of some kind - they also might have some kind of keep alive or heartbeat mechanism.